# ChartJS Bubble Chart - Control The Radius Pixel Size Based on Fixed Height Chart To Prevent Overly Large Bubbles

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I understand in ChartJS, based on the documentation of the "radius" (found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#styling), that the "radius" controls the size of the bubble.

I have a chart where the radius is based on the "count" of a specific type of value, which can sometimes be very large numbers, thus making the bubbles way too large given that the height of the view if only 400 pixel (re: screenshot below of what this looks like).

Is there a way to control the scale of the radius. So, for example, the max radius of the bubbles is "100px" then it gets smaller from "100px" down (e.g., it scales the numbers down?).

[image]

Here's my current "options" configuration for reference:

```
{
    "maintainAspectRatio": false,
    "responsive": true,
    "animation": {
        "duration": 150
    },
    "scales": {
        "y": {
            "beginAtZero": true,
            "title": {
                "display": true,
                "text": "Paid Clicks"
            }
        },
        "x": {
            "beginAtZero": true,
            "title": {
                "display": true,
                "text": "Paid Conversions"
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins": {
        "tooltip": {
            "callbacks": {}
        },
        "datalabels": {
            "display": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, here's how I did it for anyone that needs to do this in the future!

Step #1: Scaled the "r" value by the max "r"

```
    // for dataPoints, make "r" so 100 is the max radius and everything else is scaled down
    const maxRadius = Math.max(...dataPoints.map((dataPoint: Dataset) => dataPoint.data[0].r));
    dataPoints.forEach((dataPoint: Dataset) => {
        dataPoint.data[0].r = Math.round(dataPoint.data[0].r / maxRadius * MAX_ALLOWED_BUBBLE_RADIUS);
    });
```

Step #2: I'm use datalabels w/ https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/, so I needed to get the "non-scaled value" to include in the datalabel. To do this, I did the below in my options:

```
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(context: any) {
                    const label = `Group: ${context.dataset.label}`;
                    // need to get original count, since we scaled it down for the bubble chart
                    const countDatapoint = originalData.filter((dataObj: DataObject) => dataObj.label === context.dataset.label)[0].datapoint;
                    const rLabel = `Count: ${countDatapoint}`;
                    return [label, rLabel];
                }
            }
        },
    },
```